# Airflow - xcom value acess into custom operator

Tags: airflow

I am using Airlfow, since last 6 months. I felt so happy to define the workflows in Airflow.
I have the below scenario where I am not able to get the xcom value (highlighted in yellow color).

Please find the code below sample code:

## Work Flow

```
def push_function(**context):
context['ti'].xcom_push(key='reportid', value='xyz')

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(
task_id='Start',
dag=main_dag
)

push_function_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_function',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=push_function,
    op_kwargs={},
    dag=main_dag)


push_function_task .set_upstream(dummy_operator)

custom_task = CustomOperator(
        dag=main_dag,
        task_id='import_data',
        provide_context=True,
        url="http://www.google.com/{}".format("{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_function')}}")

     )

custom_task .set_upstream(push_function_task)
```

**Notes**:
1. CustomOperator is my own operator wtritten for downloading the data for the given URL

Please help me.

Thanks,
Samanth

Comment: There is no yellow highlight. Is the field `url` templated in your definition of `CustomOperator`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you have a mismatch in keys when pushing and pulling the XCom. Each XCom value is tied to a DAG ID, task ID, and key. If you are pushing with `report_id` key, then you need to pull with it as well.

Note, if a key is not specified to `xcom_pull()`, it uses the default of `return_value`. This is because if a task returns a result, Airflow will automatically push it to XCom under the `return_value` key.

This gives you two options to fix your issue:

1) Continue to push to the `report_id` key and make sure you pull from it as well

```
def push_function(**context):
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='reportid', value='xyz')

...

custom_task = CustomOperator(
    ...
    url="http://www.google.com/{}".format("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_function', key='reportid') }}")
)
```

2) Have `push_function()` return the value you want to push to XCom, then pull from the default key.

```
def push_function(**context):
    return 'xyz'

...

custom_task = CustomOperator(
    ...
    url="http://www.google.com/{}".format("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_function') }}")
)
```